# Chromecast can't load mp3?

Tags: mp3, chromecast

I've an issue with a Chromecast app I'm working on. It's an app for Chrome (not for iOS or Android).

I can't figure out why mp3 files aren't loaded by my chromecast device while mp4 are (for the record, I'm using the default receiver).

I based my work on this official sample : https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome

Here you can see the code : http://pastebin.com/nJGeT7xP

Here is how I send the mp3 file :

```
if (session) {
  var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo("http://localhost/tom_www/CastTom/music.mp3", "audio/mpeg");
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
  session.loadMedia(
    request,
    onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'),
    onMediaError
  );
} else {
  console.log("No session available, connect first");
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to use a real address and not localhost. You will need to put the mp3 in a public location or get the ipaddress of your chrome device to send to the chromecast.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems so obvious now! It works now! Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. I have put my comment as an answer as it was mostly an educated guess as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put the mp3 in a location accessible to the chromecast.  You can do this by getting the the ipaddress of your chrome device to send to the chromecast or placing the mp3 on a publicly accessible server.